# How to Use this Python Event API

Tags: python, events, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is an event API defined at https://github.com/jrowberg/bglib/blob/master/Python/bglib.py. But since I'm new to Python I can't understand how to use that.

For example, what should I do in my code to listen to the event `ble_rsp_system_hello`?

What is the significance of `__get__` and `__set__` methods in the `BGAPIEvent` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out and verified using a test.
Following is the way to do it.

```
ble = bglib.BGLib()
ser = serial.Serial(port="/dev/ttyACM1", baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
ble.send_command(ser, ble.ble_cmd_gap_set_mode(0x82, 0x01)

def handler(sender, earg):
    print earg['address']

ble.ble_rsp_system_address_get += handle

while (1):
        # check for all incoming data (no timeout, non-blocking)
        ble.check_activity(ser)

        # don't burden the CPU
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

More information can be found [here](http://emptypage.jp/notes/pyevent.en.html),